# Is it NP-hard to check whether for a $k$ there exist both a Cut and a Bisection of value $k$?

Tags: np-hard, decision-problem

Input: An undirected, unweighted graph $G=(V,E)$.

A cut is defined as a partition $V=A\dot\cup B$.

A bisection is defined as a partition $V=A\dot\cup B$ with $|A|=|B|$ if $|V|$ is even (or $|A|= |B|+1$ if $|V|$ is odd).

We define the value of a cut/bisection $V=A\dot\cup B$ as $E[A,B]$, i.e. as the number of edges between the partitions.

Question:

Is it NP-hard to solve the following problem:
Given an integer $k$, do there exist both a Cut and a Bisection of value $k$?

The problem is in NP, because given a cut and a bisection, we can efficiently check whether both have value $k$.

I'm also wondering whether there are somewhat general techniques that help one decide the NP-hardness of a problem which is more or less two NP-hard problems slapped together by an equality.

---

Literature:

NP-completeness of Max-Cut: [DOI:10.1016/0304-3975(76)90059-1](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Some-Simplified-NP-Complete-Graph-Problems-Garey-Johnson/18199ef67e170ba4f379ab45a8cc2581994e9178)

NP-completeness of Vertex Bisection: [DOI=10.1.1.154.5438](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.154.5438)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127042/discussion-on-question-by-sudix-is-it-np-hard-to-check-whether-the-max-cut-occur).

Comment: The title of your question does not match the problem listed in the body of your question.  I encourage you to [edit] the question to improve the title.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is equivalent to the following:

Given an integer $k$, does there exist a bisection of value $k$?

In particular, every bisection is a cut, so if there exists a bisection of value $k$, then there also exists a cut of value $k$; if there does not exist a bisection of value $k$, then there does not exist both a cut and a bisection of value $k$.

This revised problem is NP-complete -- it follows from the NP-hardness of the maximum bisection problem.  So, your problem is NP-complete, too (since it is the same problem).